# Facebook Ads API returns unique_impressions = 0 for multiple day stats query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-ads-api

When requesting ad stat for an add that is running longer than 1 day I recieve `unique_imperssion = 0.`

However when requesting stats for a day the unique_impression is populated.

Is it a bug or intentional? is there a workaround to get unique impressions for more than 1 day?

**Querying for one day:**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<ad_group_id>/stats/1362787200/1362873600
```

**I get:**

```
{
   "id": "<ad_group_id>/stats/1362787200/1362873600",
   "impressions": 8616,
   "clicks": 67,
   "spent": 715,
   "social_impressions": 20,
   "social_clicks": 0,
   "social_spent": 0,

   "unique_impressions": 3544,

   "social_unique_impressions": 11,
   "unique_clicks": 67,
   "social_unique_clicks": 0,
   "actions": null,
   "inline_actions": {
      "title_clicks": 0,
      "like": 9,
      "rsvp_yes": 0,
      "rsvp_maybe": 0,
      "post_like": 0,
      "comment": 0,
      "photo_view": 0,
      "link_click": 0,
      "video_play": 0,
      "question_vote": 0
   },...
```

**Querying for all time:**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<ad_group_id>/stats
```

**I get:**

```
{
   "id": "<ad_group_id>/stats",
   "impressions": 8616,
   "clicks": 67,
   "spent": 715,
   "social_impressions": 20,
   "social_clicks": 0,
   "social_spent": 0,

   "unique_impressions": 0,

   "social_unique_impressions": 11,
   "unique_clicks": 67,
   "social_unique_clicks": 0,
   "actions": null,
   "inline_actions": {
      "title_clicks": 0,
      "like": 9,
      "rsvp_yes": 0,
      "rsvp_maybe": 0,
      "post_like": 0,
      "comment": 0,
      "photo_view": 0,
      "link_click": 0,
      "video_play": 0,
      "question_vote": 0
   },...
```

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

Are you forgetting to use timestamps which are for a 1, 7 or 28 day period, and adjusted to match the timezone of the ad account itself? This is the most likely explanation here

For example, if your ad account (`/act_<ACCOUNT_NUMBER_HERE`) is like this:

```
  "account_id": "<SNIP>", 
  "id": "act_<SNIP", 
  "name": "<SNIP> default (EUR) account", 
  "account_status": 1, 
  "currency": "EUR", 
  "timezone_id": 69, 
  "timezone_name": "Europe/Dublin", 
  "timezone_offset_hours_utc": 1,
```

You need to adjust the timestamps of your stats calls to UTC +1

So for retrieving unique stats, you need to request 1, 7 or 28 days of data, from midnight-midnight, in UTC +1 , this example should work for you:

`<SNIP>/stats/2013-02-01 00:00:00 +0100/2013-03-01 00:00:00 +0100`

or

`<SNIP>/stats/1359673200/1362092400`

Example response (truncated)

```
{
  "id": "<SNIP>/stats/1359673200/1362092400", 
  "impressions": "166561", 
  "clicks": "6304", 
  "spent": "45257", 
  "social_impressions": "166556", 
  "social_clicks": "6304", 
  "social_spent": "45257", 
  "unique_impressions": 111368, 
  "social_unique_impressions": 111368, 
  "unique_clicks": 5992, 
  "social_unique_clicks": 5992, 
  "actions": {
```